# How to display Custom Object field in Lightning Component ComboBox?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am new to Lightning Page, so I don't know how to display Custom Object field in Combobox? Is there a way that similar to how it functions in ApexCode?
I have this lightning component code:

```
<lightning:comboBox label="Lớp"
                    options={options}
                    onchange={handleChange}></lightning:comboBox>
```

and js code but don't know what I should write in it:

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        
    }
})
```

I used to do the same thing back in Visualforce Pages.
Visualforce:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!hs.LOP__c}" size="1" multiselect="false">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!lop}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
```

ApexCode:

```
public List<SelectOption> getlop()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<LOP__c> dsLop = [SELECT ID, TEN__c FROM LOP__c ORDER BY TEN__c];
        for(LOP__c lop : dsLop)
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(lop.ID), lop.TEN__c));
        }
        
        return options;
    }
```

I need some help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the similar apex class but with a list and return it.

In the JS, you need to create a objects list and iterate over the string list and in the objects is necessary to fill a label and value.

Similar to this:

```
var lops = [];
if(lopLst.length > 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < issueOpt.length; i++){
        
        var item = {
            "label": lopList[i],
            "value": issueOpt[i]
        };
        lops.push(item);                            
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you explain it more specifically for me? Thank you.